# Why can't I have topics published when running vrpn_client_ros node

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I connect my lap top to the Vicon tracker and run vrpn_client_node usually I have this (image1 bellow) where it is written found new sender and my object name.

[image: Image1]

But now I don't know what I did, I am no longer having those lines when I run the node (Image2 bellow)

[image: Image2]

Any suggestion what I might did wrong!! Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357873/why-can%27t-i-have-topics-published-when-running-vrpn_client_ros-node/) by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-07-23**:
Usually, I face this issue when I'm not on the same network as the mocap system (optitrack in my case)  or when the data transmission is disabled on the mocap system.

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2020-07-23**:
OK thanks I ll check :)

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2020-07-24**:
yeah, they weren't on the same network and I spend the whole afternoon try to find what is the problem thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To summarise, even when we see the `connection established` it doesn't necessarily mean the vrpn system is connected. Usually, we receive some information about the vrpn version on the connected system.

- Ensure that both systems are on the correct network
- Vrpn is enabled on the relevant systems

---

Originally posted by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) with karma: 257 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0